# I cannot connect jsp pages to mysql server

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc

I am using tomcat 6.0
This is my catalina home -> C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0

I am using jdk 1.6 
This is my JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24

I am using windows 7

OK i wrote a jsp page
This is the code
Its saved in -> C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\myapp\wow.jsp

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%
   String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/unni";
   Connection connection = null;
   Statement statement = null;
   ResultSet rs = null;
   %>



    <%
    Class.forName("com.mysql.Driver").newInstance();
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "footyfreak");
    statement = connection.createStatement();
    rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM unni");

    while (rs.next()) {
       out.println(rs.getString("player")+"");
    }

    rs.close();
    %>
```

I downloaded connector and copied it to :- 
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\myapp\WEB-INF\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar

and also to 
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar

Then when I hit url 
http://localhost:8080/myapp/wow.jsp

I get an error as -------------->

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /wow.jsp at line 12

9:    
10: 
11:     <%
12:     Class.forName("com.mysql.Driver").newInstance();
13:     connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "footyfreak");
14:     statement = connection.createStatement();
15:     rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM unni");


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:519)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:410)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.Driver
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:865)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:794)
    org.apache.jsp.wow_jsp._jspService(wow_jsp.java:84)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.Driver
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:128)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:66)
    java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.jsp.wow_jsp._jspService(wow_jsp.java:68)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.32 logs.
Apache Tomcat/6.0.32
```

My classpath details are

```
variable : CLASSPATH
value    : C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\lib\servlet-api.jar ; C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar;
```

Help me out. I have been sitting on this for days.

I did just as in the documentation.

Is there nething to be done apart from whats mentioned here?

Answer (score 3):

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.Driver

The class name is wrong. It is `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

That `newInstance()` call is by the way superfluous. Please note that putting all that code inside a JSP file is a poor practice. That code should usually go in normal Java classes which you use in a servlet. Also note that the `CLASSPATH` environment variable is totally ignored when running Tomcat.

#### See also:

- [Java connectivity with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/java-connectivity-with-mysql/2840358#2840358)
- [How to avoid Java code in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

Comment: +1, Good found. I think I need to buy a new specs.... ;-) Do you think jars will conflict? OP has added same jar in two places.

Comment: @Harry: My specs are about one month ago renewed. As to the duplicate JARs, it won't conflict if they are exactly the same, but this is indeed not necessarily the best practice.

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
Now this is the error i am getting :(

Comment: about the jars. I deleted the one in the Tomcat 6.0\lib

Comment: It has got to be in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder of the webapp. Are you using an IDE?

Comment: Then the lib is just not there where it should be or you started/accessed the wrong Tomcat instance or the wrong webapp.

Answer (score 0):

connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "footyfreak");
In this connectionURL statement you want to give your database name. Example:
`String st="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/staff";
    Connection con=null;
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(st,"root","admin" );`
In this example, staff is my database name.
After giving like this, I didnt get that error message.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding external jar copy the jar file to the following location

```
WEB-INF/lib
```